# Why am I getting a Java IO Exception in this very simple code?

Tags: input, groovy, stream, output

The following is some sample code I created to get myself more familiar with Groovy. I have a good understanding of Java and I am trying to now learn this new language.

```
class Activity {

    static void reverseString() {

        def text

        System.in.withReader{

            println "Enter a string to be reversed:"
            text = it.readLine()
        }


        print "\n";
        for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

            print text[i];

        }
    }


    static void main(String[] args) {

        def selection

        System.in.withReader{

            println "Select a project:"
            println "1 - Reverse String"
            selection = it.readLine()

        }

        switch (selection) {

            case "1":
                reverseString()
                break
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to compile and run this code. I am able to enter '1' and press enter, and then the prompt from my method shows up. At this point I am supposed to enter a string to reverse, but before I can enter I get the IO Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>
> at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
>
> at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
>
> at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
>
> at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
>
> at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
>
> at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:127)
>
> at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
>
> at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
>
> at Activity$_reverseString_closure1.doCall(main.groovy:10)
>
> at Activity.reverseString(main.groovy:7)
>
> at Activity.main(main.groovy:39)

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Stream closed" - the exception tells you why.

Comment: Why is the stream closed? @duffymo

Comment: It even tells you the line number.  This is the chance to exercise your debugging skills.  Do you have an IDE?  Set a breakpoint and step through.  You'd already have the answer if you had.

Comment: Why do you have input in the reverseString method?  A better, more reusable solution would be to ask for the string inside the main method and pass it to reverseString.

Comment: Right, and the line the error refers to is simply the input line, where the use has to input their answer. The syntax and format used for this was the same as my first user input section, there are no differences. Which is why I'm confused on why one works but the other doesn't.

Comment: Try my suggestion.  You should NOT be prompting for input in a method that way.  Move that out of the method and pass the string in.  It'll be more reusable.

Comment: @duffymo yes you're right, I will do that for sure. But I was just confused on this specific case where I open the stream again. Can I not call withReader() twice to open the stream again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `withReader()` is to ensure the stream is closed. So after the project selection is input in the `main()` method, the stream is closed. When `reverseString()` is executed, it's too late; the stream is closed.

Don't close `System.in` (directly, or through `withReader`) . Only close streams that your code creates, not streams that your application receives from a caller, or global instances in the runtime.

Comment: How do I open the stream to allow multiple reads? I know there is the scanner method, but are there Groovy specific ways to do this?

Comment: @LakshanSivananthan You don't open, and shouldn't close, `System.in`. It's a stream managed by the runtime. So "opening the stream to allow multiple reads" is the wrong approach. The `reverseString()` method should accept a stream as a parameter, and rely on the caller to open and close it.

Comment: @erickson whoops... Brain freeze... Deleted